# How to handle encoded inputs that need to be edited?

Tags: html-encode, antixsslibrary

Using Microsoft's AntiXssLibrary, how do you handle input that needs to be edited later?

For example:

User enters:
    `<i>title</i>`

Saved to the database as:
   `<i>title</i>`

On an edit page, in a text box it displays something like: 
    `&lt;i&gt;title&lt;/i&gt;` because I've encoded it before displaying in the text box.

User doesn't like that.

Is it ok not to encode when writing to an input control?

Update:

I'm still trying to figure this out.  The answers below seem to say to decode the string before displaying, but wouldn't that allow for XSS attacks?

The one user who said that decoding the string in an input field value is ok was downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're encoding it more than once. In ASP.NET, using Microsoft's AntiXss Library you can use the HtmlAttributeEncode method to encode untrusted input:

```
<input type="text" value="<%= AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode("<i>title</i>") %>" />
```

This results in

```
<input type="text" value="&#60;i&#62;title&#60;&#47;i&#62;" />
```

in the rendered page's markup and is correctly displayed as `<i>title</i>` in the input box.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be double-encoding; the HTML needs to be escaped once (so it can be inserted into the HTML on the page without issue), but twice leads to the encoded version appearing literally.

Comment: What about when you are inserting it into an input field so that users can edit it?  Should it be encoded?

Answer (score 0):

You can call HTTPUtility.HTMLDecode(MyString) to get the text back to the unencoded form.

Comment: One of the problems I face is that I'm using the AntiXssLibrary and it doesn't seem to have an HtmlDecode method.  I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing users to enter HTML that will then be rendered on the site, you need to do more than just Encode and Decode it.

Using AntiXss prevents attacks by converting script and markup to text. It does not do anything to "clean" markup that will be rendered directly. You're going to have to manually remove script tags, etc. from the user's input to be fully protected in that scenario.

You'll need to strip out script tags as well as JavaScript attributes on legal elements. For example, an attacker could inject malicious code into the onclick or onmouseover attributes.

Comment: Is this true?  I was under the impression that the AntiXSS library was made for this scenario since html.encode does not handle it.  A Microsoft consultant even gave a presentation about how AntiXSS handles this while html.encode does not.  The point being that we should use AntiXSS.  I guess I will need to test this out.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, the code inside input boxes is safe from scripting attacks and does not need to be encoded.